# Perl: foreach and sort

Tags: perl, sorting, loops

I'm writing a little program that I  need to sort the results in.  Basically, I have a `foreach` loop that gets its data from a subroutine.  Here's the code:

```
foreach $host (get_mirror_list()) {
    (my $ret, my $dur, my $ip) = $p->ping($host,2);
    my $duration = 1000 * $dur;
    my $results = printf("$host:%.2f\n", $duration) if $ret;
}
```

I need to know how I can process in the `foreach` statement, and then store the data into a `hash` or array (not sure what to do) and then sort part of the data after.  I'm pretty new to Perl and I only dabble in it here and there.  By the way, the `foreach` statement works, I just don't know how to go about the sorting and storing the data.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you initializing variables that you never seem to use (namely, both `@results_array` and the (scalar!) `$results_array`)?

Comment: For that matter, what is `$p`?  You need to post more code around this loop so that we can get more context.

Comment: fyi When you initialize variables as a group you should do my ($ret, $dur, $ip) = $p->ping($host,2); rather than (my $ret, my $dur, my $ip) = $p->ping($host,2);

Comment: Or stuff the values into a hash using a hash slice: `my %res; @res{qw{ret dur ip}} = $p->ping($host, 2);`

Comment: There seems to be something missing in this sentence: `"I need to know how I can process in the foreach statement"` Is this a typo?

Comment: @drew I have edited your question to remove code which was completely useless. If you feel this was an error, simply roll back your question.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you're trying to do, but the following should take the results from `$p->ping` and stuff them into an array, then displays them sorted by host.

```
...

my @results;

foreach my $host (get_mirror_list()) {
    my %ping_res = ( host => $host );

    @ping_res{qw{ ret dur ip }} = $p->ping($host, 2);

    push @results, \%ping_res;
}

foreach my $pr (sort { $$a{host} <=> $$b{host} } @results) {
    if ($$pr{ret}) {
        printf("%s:%.2f\n", $$pr{host}, 1000 * $$pr{dur});
    }
}
...
```

Or, if you like, put the results in a hash:

```
...

my %results;

foreach my $host (get_mirror_list()) {
    my %ping_res;

    @ping_res{qw{ ret dur ip }} = $p->ping($host, 2);

    $results{$host} = \%ping_res;
}

foreach my $host (sort keys %results) {
    my $pr = $results{$host};

    if ($$pr{ret}) {
        printf("%s:%.2f\n", $host, 1000 * $$pr{dur});
    }
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my ($HOST, $RTT, $DUR, $IP) = ( 0 .. 3 );
my @slow_mirrors = sort { $b->[$RTT] <=> $a->[$RTT] } 
                   grep { $_->[$RTT] > .5 } 
                   map { [ $_, $p->ping($_, 2) ] } get_mirror_list();


for my $system (@slow_mirrors) {
    say "$system->[$HOST] ($system->[$IP]) is slow: $system->[$RTT] ms round trip time."
}
```

Comment: Your sort function looks a bit dicey :-)